# Is there a way to configure VS Code to format code at the bottom of the editor instead of at the top when there is extra space in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for something that detects when a file's content does not fill the entire viewport of the editor, then adds extra space at the TOP of the file instead of at the BOTTOM.

VSCode *does* offer the option to add a default padding at the top of editors but it doesn't automatically display the padding when opening the file (and this isn't exactly the functionality I'm looking for either, since that would be inconvenient for larger files that take up more space than the viewport of the editor).

Bonus points if someone knows the answer to this for IntelliJ as well (if it exists) :)

How it looks now:

[image: How it looks now]

What I'm looking for:

[image: What I'm looking for]

Comment: why do you want this ?

Comment: @Curcuma_ I have my monitor set up vertically and it would be nice if I didn't have to look up at the very top of my monitor when I am writing a new file. I like to have the editor take up the entire screen as it's great for navigating through a file, but in this scenario it can be less than ideal.